# How to Show Data from Database into textbox

Tags: javascript, php, html

In this code, I want to show data from database into textbox.

But when I press show button I get error:

> (Notice: Undefined index: first_name )

What I do then data show in textbox?

```
**//BootStrap Code**
        <tr>
              <th scope="row"></th>
             <td><label class="control-label" for="finame" id="myID1" >FIRST NAME</label></td>
            <td><input value="<?php $_POST['first_name']?>"  type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase"name="firstname" onkeypress="return allCharacter(event);" ></td>
            <td><label  class="control-label" for="mname">MIDDLE NAME</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="middlename"></td>
            <td><label  class="control-label" for="lname" id="myID2">LAST NAME</label></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="  form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase" name="lastname" onkeypress="return allCharacter(event);"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>

**//php code**
    if(isset($_POST['select_button'])){

                $myquery='SELECT ecode, first_name, middle_name, last_name, father_name, mother_name,
              number_of_dependents, dob, gender, identification_mark, marital_status, spouse_name, mobile_number,
              email_id, adhar_id, pan_number, passport_number, tin_number, dl_number FROM USER_MASTER';

        $fetched=mysql_query($myquery)or die(mysql_error());;

        while($rowvalue=mysql_fetch_array($fetched)){
            echo $rowvalue['first_name'];   
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to get raw printed multiple times as per records availible in database?

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `first_name` in the `$_POST` array when it doesn't look like you ever post that value.

Providing your query is returning the value correctly you can do something like this

PHP code:

```
   $fetched=mysql_query($myquery)or die(mysql_error());

    while($rowvalue=mysql_fetch_array($fetched))
    {
        $first_name = $rowvalue['first_name']; // save the name from the query
    }
```

HTML code:

```
<td><input value="<?= $first_name ?>"  type="text" class=" form-control2 input-sm text-uppercase"name="firstname" onkeypress="return allCharacter(event);" ></td>
```

Assuming your SQL query is successful and you save it to a variable to use later this should do the trick. If you are still having troubles reply and I can do some further testing - it's a bit tricky without the full code posted.

Comment: Hello friend when i put value="<?= $first_name ?>"  then it show's $first_name seems to be uninitialized

Comment: Is your SQL query definitely working and returning it? Is it echoing out the first_name like you ask it to inside your `foreach` loop? Also you need to make sure that your `foreach` loop is above the HTML where you echo `$first_name` as otherwise it will say its uninitialized.

Comment: when i put echo $rowvalue['first_name']; then is shows all names from database but not in textbox , it's shows on page

Comment: And in that loop you are initializing the variable by having `$first_name = $rowvalue['first_name'];` and that loop is above the inputbox on the page?

Comment: actually i have a time limit of 90 miniuts for posting other code otherwise i will post my code here

Comment: You need to have the loop at the top of the page, or at least above the code where you do `<?= $first_name ?>`. Otherwise when your inputbox tries to get the `$first_name` it cannot find it because you haven't initialized it yet.

Comment: i want to show data into text box but it shows error Notice: Undefined index: first_name

Comment: Please make sure you are doing what i mentioned in my previous comment, otherwise it's going to be very hard to help more without the full code.

Comment: i put my php code above the input text box , $first_name seems to be uninitialized has gone but when i run program then it shows- Notice: Undefined variable: first_name

Comment: Unfortunately without seeing your full code it's going to be too confusing to give assistance.